# py2neo Graph.find_one() deprecation warning?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have py2neo version 3.1.2 installed on python 3.5 and when I run the following code, I receive a deprecation warning about Graph.find_one and am told to use NodeSelector instead. [v3 Documentation](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.find_one) doesn't mention this depreciation. When I go to use the NodeSelector method in the code below I end up with many duplicate calendar nodes all linked to a single event node. How do I update my code to prevent this warning?

There are already a number of calendar nodes on my graph. I want this to go through this dictionary and append them to the graph and relate them to the appropriate calendar node.

```
for k,v in calendar_dict.items():
    calendar = graph.find_one("Calendar", property_key='url', property_value=v[2])
    calendar_event = Node("CalendarEvent", event=k, date=str(v[0]))
    graph.create(calendar_event)
    calendar_rel = Relationship(calendar_event, "POSTED_ON", calendar, 
                                scrape_date=str(datetime.date.today()))
    graph.create(calendar_rel)
```

**Warning**

```
/home/mcamp/anaconda3/envs/py3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:2: DeprecationWarning: Graph.find_one is deprecated, use NodeSelector instead
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find_one is deprecated and is indicated in the [source](http://py2neo.org/v3/_modules/py2neo/database.html#Graph.exists)

To solve your issue use NodeSelector equivalent function is [NodeSelection.first](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.selection.NodeSelection.first)